# Converting number to words in React.js

Tags: reactjs

Trying to convert numbers to words. It converts non-decimal numbers, but when it comes to decimals it shows `undefined` for decimal parts like for number e.g. 118.65. It shows undefined rupees only instead of one hundred eighteen rupees and sixty five paisa only.

- Input given: 118.65
- Actual output: one hundred unedined rupees only
- Expected output: one hundred eighteen Rupees and sixty five paisa only

```js
function App() {
  return <Textword grandtotalAmount={118.65} />;
}

function Textword({ grandtotalAmount }) {
  const convertNumberToWords = (number) => {
    const units = [
      "",
      "One",
      "Two",
      "Three",
      "Four",
      "Five",
      "Six",
      "Seven",
      "Eight",
      "Nine",
    ];
    const tens = [
      "",
      "Ten",
      "Twenty",
      "Thirty",
      "Forty",
      "Fifty",
      "Sixty",
      "Seventy",
      "Eighty",
      "Ninety",
    ];
    const teens = [
      "Ten",
      "Eleven",
      "Twelve",
      "Thirteen",
      "Fourteen",
      "Fifteen",
      "Sixteen",
      "Seventeen",
      "Eighteen",
      "Nineteen",
    ];
    const crore = "Crore";
    const lakh = "Lakh";
    const arab = "Arab";
    const currency = "Rupees";
    const paisa = "Paisa";
    
    if (number === 0) {
      return "Zero " + currency;
    }

    let words = "";
    
    if (number >= 1000000000) {
      words +=
        convertNumberToWords(Math.floor(number / 1000000000)) +
        " " +
        arab +
        " ";
      number %= 1000000000;
    }
    if (number >= 10000000) {
      words +=
        convertNumberToWords(Math.floor(number / 10000000)) + " " + crore + " ";
      number %= 10000000;
    }

    if (number >= 100000) {
      words +=
        convertNumberToWords(Math.floor(number / 100000)) + " " + lakh + " ";
      number %= 100000;
    }

    if (number >= 1000) {
      words += convertNumberToWords(Math.floor(number / 1000)) + " Thousand ";
      number %= 1000;
    }

    if (number >= 100) {
      words += convertNumberToWords(Math.floor(number / 100)) + " Hundred ";
      number %= 100;
    }

    if (number >= 20) {
      words += tens[Math.floor(number / 10)] + " ";
      number %= 10;
    } else if (number >= 10) {
      console.log(number);
      words += teens[number - 10] + " ";
      number = 0;
      console.log(words);
    }

    if (number > 0) {
      words += units[number] + " ";
    }
    const decimalPart = Math.round((number % 1) * 100);
    console.log(decimalPart);
    if (decimalPart > 0) {
      words += "and" + decimalPart + " " + paisa + "only ";
    }
    
    console.log(words);
    return words.trim() + " ";
  };

  let grandTotal = grandtotalAmount; // Example value
  let amountWord = convertNumberToWords(grandTotal);
  console.log(amountWord);
  return <React.Fragment>{amountWord}</React.Fragment>;
}

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
  .render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: Gotta change the data type it is expect to allow for decimals.  Integers are whole numbers.  Normal math operations only work with "real" whole numbers, so you will have to do the converting and then combine the two types.

Answer (score 0):

The following modifications should take place:

- The `words` field should be an array
- You can move the `convertNumberToWords` outside of the component
- The `convertNumberToWords` will need an inner recursive function that considers its own words
- You can reuse the inner `convert` to handle the decimal portion

Here is a working example:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><Textword grandtotalAmount={0} /></li>
        <li><Textword grandtotalAmount={0.69} /></li>
        <li><Textword grandtotalAmount={118.65} /></li>
        <li><Textword grandtotalAmount={987654321.42} /></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

function Textword({ grandtotalAmount }) {
  return <div>{convertNumberToWords(grandtotalAmount)}</div>;
}

const units = ["", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine"];
const tens = ["", "Ten", "Twenty", "Thirty", "Forty", "Fifty", "Sixty", "Seventy", "Eighty", "Ninety"];
const teens = ["Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen"];

const zero = "Zero";
const arab = "Arab";
const crore = "Crore";
const lakh = "Lakh";
const thousand = "Thousand";
const hundred = "Hundred";
const currency = "Rupees";
const paisa = "Paisa";
const only = "Only";

function convertNumberToWords(amount) {
  if (amount === 0) return `${zero} ${currency} ${only}`;
  
  function convert(num) {
    let parts = [];
    if (num >= 1e9) {
      parts.push(`${convert(Math.floor(num / 1e9))} ${arab}`);
      num %= 1e9;
    }
    if (num >= 1e7) {
      parts.push(`${convert(Math.floor(num / 1e7))} ${crore}`);
      num %= 1e7;
    }
    if (num >= 1e5) {
      parts.push(`${convert(Math.floor(num / 1e5))} ${lakh}`);
      num %= 1e5;
    }
    if (num >= 1000) {
      parts.push(`${convert(Math.floor(num / 1000))} ${thousand}`);
      num %= 1000;
    }
    if (num >= 100) {
      parts.push(`${convert(Math.floor(num / 100))} ${hundred}`);
      num %= 100;
    }
    if (num >= 20) {
      parts.push(`${tens[Math.floor(num / 10)]}`);
      if (num % 10 > 0) parts.push(units[num % 10]);
    } else if (num >= 10) {
      parts.push(`${teens[num - 10]}`);
    } else if (num > 0) {
      parts.push(`${units[num]}`);
    }
    return parts.join(" ");
  }

  let integerPart = Math.floor(amount);
  let wholeWordPart = convert(integerPart);
  let result = wholeWordPart ? `${wholeWordPart} ${currency}` : '';

  let decimalPart = Math.round((amount - integerPart) * 100);
  if (decimalPart > 0) {
    if (wholeWordPart) {
      result += " and ";
    }
    result += `${convert(decimalPart)} ${paisa}`;
  }

  return `${result} ${only}`;
}

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
  .render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `number-to-words` module.

Pleaze check this url of [number to words module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/number-to-words).

This is an example:

```
var converter = require('number-to-words');
converter.toWords(13); // => “thirteen”
 
// Decimal numbers:
converter.toWords(2.9); // => “two”
 
// Negative numbers:
converter.toWords(-3); // => “minus three”
 
// Large numbers:
converter.toWords(9007199254740992); // => “nine quadrillion, seven trillion, one hundred ninety-nine billion, two hundred fifty-four million, seven hundred forty thousand, nine hundred ninety-two”
```

Also you can add CDN link in your project.

`<script src=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/number-to-words@1.2.4/numberToWords.min.js "></script>`